# Identifying object in ItemTemplate and event not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, telerik, rad-controls

I am using a RadListView control with an ItemTemplate that contains a button as shown here:

```
<ItemTemplate>
    <tr class="rlvI">
        //more TD elements here
        <td>
            <telerik:RadButton ID="ENABLEDToggle" runat="server" Width="75" ButtonType="StandardButton" AutoPostBack="true"
            ToggleType="CustomToggle" Checked='<%# Enabled_Converter(Eval("ENABLED")) %>' OnCheckedChanged="TaskStateChange_Clicked">
                <ToggleStates>
                    <telerik:RadButtonToggleState Text="Enabled" />
                    <telerik:RadButtonToggleState Text="Disabled" />
                </ToggleStates>
            </telerik:RadButton>
        </td>
    </tr>
</ItemTemplate>
```

My first question is why is it that when my button is pressed, I do not enter my TaskStateChange_Clicked event handler? It is as if the event is never fired.

Second, whenever a button is clicked, how do I get the object associated with that row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for the first question, check how you are binding your `RadListView`. Problems like this usually appear if controls are bound with data on every postback. So if you have something like

```
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    RadListView1.DataSource = dataSource;
    RadListView1.DataBind();
    ...
}
```

replace it with

```
void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        RadListView1.DataSource = dataSource;
        RadListView1.DataBind();
    }
    ...
}
```

**Update from comments.** Another reason might be that the type of your button is `StandardButton` while [spec](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/button-server-side-properties-events.html) implies that event `CheckedChanged` is fired only when button type is `ToggleButton`.

As for the second question consider using RadListView's `ItemCommand` event. This way you can make use of `CommandArgument` property of `RadButton` and pass any info you want in it, say object's ID.

Comment: I am using `if(!Page.IsPostBack)` and am setting the datasource in there.

Comment: @Justin, another reason might be that the type of your button is `StandardButton` while [spec](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/button-server-side-properties-events.html) implies that event `CheckedChanged` is fired only when button type is `ToggleButton`.

Comment: You lead me down the right track. I changed the button type to toggle button and used the `OnToggleStateChanged` event instead. Now it is entering the event handler. Strangely, with it being a `ToggleButton` type, `CheckedChanged` still wasn't being fired.

Comment: I have one further question for you if you don't mind. I am using the `ItemCommand` as you mentioned, but when I look at the `ListViewItem` in the `RadListViewCommandEventArgs`, the `DataKeysItemContainer` and `DataKeysContainer` is null. I wanted to use that to get the ID column out of the row.

Comment: @Justin, you have two options. Either specify id field name in the `DataKeyNames` property of the `RadListView` - that should populate data keys container with values. Or initialize button's `CommandArgument` property during data binding, like that: `CommandArgument='<%# Eval("IdFieldName") %>'` - that will give you a string containing id in the Command event handler. Hope I didn't make it sound too complicated.

Comment: Thanks again. I just started using these telerik controls yesterday and still am learning. That `CommandArgument` was just what I needed.